# Is it possible to do a project with html,css,typescript,nodeJS, If possible give me any reference for that?

Tags: typescript

> I am confusing to do what is the best way to do this, any experts can give me a best suggestion on it. Thanks advance

Comment: Could you give more details about the project you have in mind ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Follow the instructions behind this link and you'll have a running project based on angular, using typescript, HTML and CSS inside nodejs. https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: No, this not related to angular

Comment: my requirement is :  i want to display a message from an API through Typescript code only with out angular